# deleting all default styling in css wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

if you will need to strip all default css in a wordpress theme is it easiest to just create a new theme from scratch or a child theme? for instance if I were to be making a custom blog would it be easiest to use canvas as the parent theme? Or would I be better off creating a new theme from scratch. I have experience in frontend development but I haven't ever worked with theming in wordpress.

Comment: If you really mean CSS, and not layout structure, simply remove or disable the stylesheet. Most themes have a primary file and possibly subordinate (browser-specific) files. If you want to create a custom layout structure, you'll probably need to do as a.barbieri suggests and start with a bare theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to start from a raw theme. 
I've been using Bare Bones several times ( http://themble.com/bones/ ).

As they say: Keep what you need, remove what you don't. It's totally up to you.